# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 147: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to send a file and params to an endpoint of FastAPI, but i am getting the following error (on the title).

My code

```
response = requests.post(url=f'{os.environ["URL"]}/summarize',
                         files=[('files', open(file[0].name, 'rb'))],
                         params={"oneparamter": oneparamter})
```

Endpoint

```
@app.post("/summarize")
async def get_summarize(request: Request):
    mJson = await request.json()
```

How to fix it? also I would like to send a very large text through json parameter or data parameter in the requests.post, but it looks with `files=` parameter within `POST` is impossible. Thank you

Comment: Can you post or describe the files you are sending? If the file is very large, the file has a chance to be corrupted, can the files opened using an editor?

Comment: the file is 5678_Hola.pdf, thank you. They may contain spanish accents

Comment: your request is not json, it's multipart/form-data form https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/

Comment: and how would it be the `requests.post`? thank you

Comment: with requests.post it would the same as in your question, but you might want to replace named parameter "params" (passed through query string) with "data" (passed through request body)

Comment: there is no chance it's not working, I've add the answer check it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should support `multipart/form-data` processing on the server-side

```bash
pip install fastapi python-multipart uvicorn requests
```

server (mostly copy-paste from [docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms-and-files/))

```py
from typing import Annotated

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Form, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/files/")
async def create_file(
    myfile: Annotated[UploadFile, File()],
    mytext: Annotated[str, Form()],
):
    return {
        "file_size": myfile.size,
        "text": mytext,
        "file_content_type": myfile.content_type,
        "file_content": str(await myfile.read()),
    }

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)
```

client (mostly same as yours)

```py
import requests

if __name__ == "__main__":
    r = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/files", data={
        "mytext": "hello world!"
    }, files={"myfile": open("main.py")})

    print(r.json())
```

result

```
{'file_size': 474, 'text': 'hello world!', 'file_content_type': None, 'file_content': "b'from typing import Annotated\\n\\nimport uvicorn\\nfrom fastapi import FastAPI, File, Form, UploadFil"}
```